# Password protect a single site on network

Tags: multisite, password

Id like to restrict access to a single (subdomain) subsite, so that it requires a plugin to view the site... without affecting any of the other subsites.

So for example if I have 3 subsites like this...

hide.mydomain.com
public1.mydomain.com
public2.mydomain.com

How can I hide and password protect just the hide.mydomain.com?

Can anyone help me? I'm struggling to find a solution, mainly because it seems like its harder to do with a subdomain, and not a subfolder.

Comment: If hide.mydomain.com locates in its own folder and you can use apache basic auth.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a powerful plugin such as [Multisite Privacy by WPMUDEV](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/sitewide-privacy-options-for-wordpress-mu/), or you can use the following code which I developed for a project of my own.

To use this code, either create a plugin with it that you only activate on the site to protect, or if that sounds too difficult, you can paste it into the theme's functions.php and wrap the add_action call with a conditional statement as seen below:

```
if ( get_current_blog_id() = 2 )  // Only apply privacy to blog ID 2
  add_action('wp', 'private_site');

function private_site() {

    if( $_GET['home'] == 'fix' ) { return; }

    $isLoginPage = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "wp-login.php") !== false;
    $isPhoneApp = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "xmlrpc.php") !== false;
    $wpe_cookie = 'wpe-auth';

    if( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin() && !$isLoginPage && !$isPhoneApp ) {

        // WPE: If not-authenticated, delete our cookie in case it exists.
        if ( isset($_COOKIE[$wpe_cookie]) ) setcookie($wpe_cookie,'',time()-1000000,'/');

        $shareKey = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'key', true );

        if( $_GET['key'] && is_single && $_GET['key'] == $shareKey ) {
            return;
        } else {
            $location = get_login_redirect_url( get_bloginfo( 'url') . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
            header( 'Location: ' . $location );
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        // WPE: Authenticated, so set the cookie properly.  No need if it's already set properly.
        $cookie_value = md5('wpe_auth_salty_dog|'.WPE_APIKEY);
        if ( ! isset( $_COOKIE[$wpe_cookie] ) || $_COOKIE[$wpe_cookie] != $cookie_value )
            setcookie($wpe_cookie,$cookie_value,0,'/');
    }
}

// Returns the login URL with a redirect link.

function get_login_redirect_url( $url = '' ) {

    $url = esc_url_raw( $url );
    if ( empty( $url ) ) return false;

    // setup query args
    $query_args = array(
        'redirect_to' => urlencode( $url )
    );
    return add_query_arg( $query_args, apply_filters( 'ass_login_url', wp_login_url() ) );
}
```